# mysql++ corrupted double linked list

Tags: c++, boost, mysql++

It's me again, back with more of my pointer nightmares. My previous thread lead me to find another issue in my database connector implementation that causes a corrupted double linked list error and a crash. Here is the offending code:

```
void dbase::insert() {
        dbaselogger.log( "insert() called.", 0 );
        mysqlpp::Connection conn( false );
        if ( conn.connect( dbname, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass ) ) {
                std::stringstream iss;
                iss<< "INSERT INTO `" << dbname << "`.`gd_servers` VALUES( ";
                for( int i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) {
                        iss<< mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[i] << ", ";
                }
                iss<< mysqlpp::quote_only << "0" << ", NOW() );";
                std::string is = iss.str();
                dbaselogger.log( is, 1 );
                mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query( is );
                mysqlpp::SimpleResult res = query.execute();
                if( res ) {
                        dbaselogger.log( "Data inserted successfully.", 1 );
                }
                else {
                        dbaselogger.log( "Failed to add server to database.", 2 );
                }
        }
        else {
                dbaselogger.log( "Failed to connect to database. Please ensure mysql is running, and that your credentials are correct.", 3 );
        }
        dbaselogger.log("insert() completed.", 0 );
}
```

Ever so often I get a corrupted double linked list error. I'm mystified.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You may want to use valgrind (if you can), it will probably show you an error.